# Own malted barley use

Tags: water, malt, steeping, mash-volume, barley

I malted my own barley for experiment. But I've not used them yet. I mean bought castle malt and munton's Irish Stout LME but haven't used them too yet. First, I want to brew my own malted barley, if i make a mistake i will risk them. Because, there are not any homebrew suppliers in Uzbekistan to buy things easily.

So, the barley I malted (5kg) looks like caramel amber malt from appearance. But a little lighter than it. I'd like to know how much water I should use for steeping it (5kg). I'm going to use 'brew in a bag' way.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I've malted my own barley a couple of times. Did the appearance change from unmalted to after malting? It should not change color significantly unless you dried it and it slightly baked the malt to a darker color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the water/grist ratio you want. Generally 0.33 gallons per lb is common, but much thicker and thinner ratios are used for different mash manipulations.

So 5kg = 11lb, 3.8 gallons = **14.38 Liters**

Comment: So after mash manipulation, 14.38 liters will be bottling volume? or Should I add more water pre-boiling?

Comment: @user8852720 it doesn't have to be. You can always add water to the boil, or boil off water. To adjust to your target OG. For example, you could go up to about 5 gallons and get a 1.060 OG with 11lb if it has the same sugar potential as 2-row. Keep in mind that if you roasted these grains you won't have any enzymes in them for a mash, it will need diastatic power from an other source.